# How to generate UUID from MAC address of Android device?

Tags: android

I have get MAC address of my android device. Now i want to generate UUID based on this MAC address. i have searched it on internet and found UUID generated from string method.

My code to generate UUID from string method is as follows:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(address);
                String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();
                txtView2.setText(randomUUIDString);
```

but this code is not working.

Comment: What motivation do you have for trying to generate a UUID based on your MAC?  The UUID.fromString() method will only parse valid UUID formatted strings.  These are two very different things.

Comment: sir there are 100k of records so what i want is to generate unique id of these records based on the MAC address of device

Comment: is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Again, why "based on your MAC address"?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

to use UUID.fromString, the string needs to be of UUID format. ex UUID.fromString("38400000-8cf0-11bd-b23e-10b90e4e0000")

a MAC address has the format of: "01:23:45:67:89:01"

Comment: is there any way to use MAC address to generate UUID?

Comment: what are you trying to do?  use MAC address as random seed?